# Standalone proper alignment of plots

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment, standalone

I try to set Up a document with multiple Plots for that i try to use TIKZ and Standalone. But the Problem is with the alignment of the different plots. I use `scale only axis` to make the axis all the same size to avoid aligment problems because of Y-Axis labels and bigger Numbers. Then i use `trim axis left, trim axis right` to avoid Problems with outstanding numbers. That would work when i directly include the tikzpicture to the document but when including them with standalone the Boundingbox seems to be calculatet differently, so centering the plots does not result in a proper alignment. Which is the best way to achieved proper alignment. Bad Font is a product of converting the pdf with inkscape to an png and drawing in the red lines. [image]

main file

```
 \documentclass[]{scrbook}
 \usepackage[textwidth=455.24945pt]{geometry} % 455.24945pt=160.00000mm not cm because of accuracy

 % Package for nice Graphs
 \usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx, xcolor}

 \usepackage[]{tikz}
 \usepackage{pgfplots}
 \usetikzlibrary{arrows, positioning, calc, matrix}
 \pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

 \usepackage{standalone}
 \standaloneconfig{mode=tex}
 % tex = use sourcefile, default
 % image = use existing image file produced by the source file
 % build = build image from source, then use it
 % buildmissing= only build image if it does not exist
 % buildnew = only build image if source file is newer 

 \begin{document}

    \begin{figure}[!ht]
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
        trim axis left, trim axis right, 
        scale only axis, % the width specifies the width of the axis only not the labels etc.
        width=0.75\textwidth, 
        height=0.1\textheight,
        xlabel={Some Data},
        ylabel={Some Value},
        ]
        \addplot[very thick, red, mark=x] coordinates {(0,0)
            (1,2)(2,3)
            (3,4)(4,6)
            (5,11)(6,20)
            (7,15)(8,12)
            (9,8)(10,7)
            (11,3)(12,0)};
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{A plot in the Document} 
    \end{figure}

    \begin{figure}[!ht]
        \centering
        \includestandalone{standalone_plot}
        \caption{Almost same plot but as Standalone}
    \end{figure}
    \begin{figure}[!ht]
        \centering
        \includestandalone{standalone_plot_2}
        \caption{Y-Values are getting bigger}
    \end{figure}        
    \begin{figure}[!ht]
        \centering
        \includestandalone{standalone_plot_3}
        \caption{Bigger Y-values and no Y Label}
    \end{figure}

 \end{document}
```

first standalone file

```
\documentclass[ class=scrbook, 
                convert=false,
                border=60pt,  
                ]{standalone}
% if axis option " only scale axis" is used border has to be set manually to avoid cropping of the Y-Axis Label. Including the standalone then has to be set to \standaloneconfig{mode=tex}
% Using border={0pt 0pt 0pt 0pt} seems not to work with scrbook

\usepackage[textwidth=455.24945pt]{geometry} % 455.24945pt=160.00000mm not cm because of accuracy

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots} 

\begin{document}    

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ 
    trim axis left, trim axis right, 
    scale only axis, % the width specifies the width of the axis only not the labels etc.
    width=0.75\textwidth, 
    height=0.1\textheight,
    scale only axis, 
    xmin=0,xmax=12, 
    xlabel=fractions,
    ylabel=Small Axis,
 ]
\addplot[blue, mark=x] coordinates {(0,0)
    (1,2)(2,3)
    (3,4)(4,6)
    (5,11)(6,20)
    (7,15)(8,12)
    (9,8)(10,7)
    (11,3)(12,0)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Second standalone file

```
\documentclass[ class=scrbook, 
                convert=false,
                border=60pt,  
                ]{standalone}
% if axis option " only scale axis" is used border has to be set manually to avoid cropping of the Y-Axis Label. Including the standalone then has to be set to \standaloneconfig{mode=tex}
% Using border={0pt 0pt 0pt 0pt} seems not to work with scrbook

\usepackage[textwidth=455.24945pt]{geometry} % 455.24945pt=160.00000mm not cm because of accuracy

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots} 

\begin{document}    

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ 
    trim axis left, trim axis right, 
    scale only axis, % the width specifies the width of the axis only not the labels etc.
    width=0.75\textwidth, 
    height=0.1\textheight,
    scale only axis, 
    xmin=0,xmax=12, 
    xlabel=fractions,
    ylabel=Small Axis,
 ]
\addplot[blue, mark=x] coordinates {(0,0)
    (1,2)(2,3)
    (3,4)(4,6)
    (5,11)(6,200)
    (7,15)(8,12)
    (9,8)(10,7)
    (11,3)(12,0)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Third standalone file

```
\documentclass[ class=scrbook, 
                convert=false,
                border=60pt,  
                ]{standalone}
% if axis option " only scale axis" is used border has to be set manually to avoid cropping of the Y-Axis Label. Including the standalone then has to be set to \standaloneconfig{mode=tex}
% Using border={0pt 0pt 0pt 0pt} seems not to work with scrbook

\usepackage[textwidth=455.24945pt]{geometry} % 455.24945pt=160.00000mm not cm because of accuracy

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots} 

\begin{document}    

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ 
    trim axis left, trim axis right, 
    scale only axis, % the width specifies the width of the axis only not the labels etc.
    width=0.75\textwidth, 
    height=0.1\textheight,
    scale only axis, 
    xmin=0,xmax=12, 
    xlabel=fractions,
    %ylabel=Small Axis,
 ]
\addplot[blue, mark=x] coordinates {(0,0)
    (1,2)(2,3)
    (3,4)(4,6)
    (5,11)(6,200)
    (7,15)(8,12)
    (9,8)(10,7)
    (11,3)(12,0)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Paease, provide MWE (minimal working example) for your pictures, which shoes your problem. Differences are caused with of different with of images, e.g. position x ticks labels.

Comment: Did you try putting the `includestandalone` statements in a `fbox{...}`? I guess your bounding boxes are different due to the different labels. Due to this, the position of the axes inside the bounding box is different, hence alignment will fail. I suggest putting all plots that belong to one figure in one tikz file, using pgfplots' capability to handle multiple plots

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update2** (with tikz library `external` and without `standalone`)

You can also use the tikz library `external`. Then you have to set `trim axis left,trim axis right` as an option for the `tikzpicture`.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{external_plot_1.tex}
\begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left,trim axis right]
\begin{axis}[ 
    scale only axis, 
    width=.75\textwidth, 
    height=.1\textheight,
    xmin=0,xmax=12, 
    xlabel=fractions,
    ylabel=Small Axis,
 ]
\addplot[blue, mark=x] coordinates {(0,0)
    (1,2)(2,3)
    (3,4)(4,6)
    (5,11)(6,20)
    (7,15)(8,12)
    (9,8)(10,7)
    (11,3)(12,0)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{external_plot_2.tex}
\begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left,trim axis right]
\begin{axis}[ 
    scale only axis,
    width=.75\textwidth, 
    height=.1\textheight,
    xmin=0,xmax=12, 
    xlabel=fractions,
    ylabel=Small Axis,
 ]
\addplot[blue, mark=x] coordinates {(0,0)
    (1,2)(2,3)
    (3,4)(4,6)
    (5,11)(6,200)
    (7,15)(8,12)
    (9,8)(10,7)
    (11,3)(12,0)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{external_plot_3.tex}
\begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left, trim axis right]
\begin{axis}[ 
    scale only axis, 
    width=.75\textwidth, 
    height=.1\textheight,
    xmin=0,xmax=12, 
    xlabel=fractions,
    %ylabel=Small Axis,
 ]
\addplot[blue, mark=x] coordinates {(0,0)
    (1,2)(2,3)
    (3,4)(4,6)
    (5,11)(6,200)
    (7,15)(8,12)
    (9,8)(10,7)
    (11,3)(12,0)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[]{scrbook}
\usepackage[textwidth=455.24945pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, positioning, calc, matrix}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=figures/]

\begin{document}
\tikzexternaldisable% disable
\begin{figure}[!ht]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left,trim axis right]
    \begin{axis}[
    scale only axis,
    width=.75\textwidth, 
    height=.1\textheight,
    xlabel={Some Data},
    ylabel={Some Value},
    ]
    \addplot[very thick, red, mark=x] coordinates {(0,0)
        (1,2)(2,3)
        (3,4)(4,6)
        (5,11)(6,20)
        (7,15)(8,12)
        (9,8)(10,7)
        (11,3)(12,0)};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{A plot in the Document} 
\end{figure}
\tikzexternalenable% \enable

\begin{figure}[!ht]
    \centering
    \input{external_plot_1}
    \caption{Almost same plot but as Standalone}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[!ht]
    \centering
    \input{external_plot_2}
    \caption{Y-Values are getting bigger}
\end{figure}        
\begin{figure}[!ht]
    \centering
    \input{external_plot_3}
    \caption{Bigger Y-values and no Y Label}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

One of the externalized plots:

[image]

---

**Update** (works for `mode=tex` and `mode=build`)

Here is another suggestion that calculates in the main document the desired width and height of the plots and write them in a file `plotdim.txt`. So package `geometry` can be removed from the standalone files.

Instead of `trim axis left` and `trim axis right` you can also use

```
\pgfresetboundingbox
\path
  ([xshift=-50pt]current axis.below south west)
  rectangle
  ([xshift=50pt]current axis.above north east)
;
```

[image]

Code:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{standalone_plot_1.tex}
\documentclass[convert=false,class=scrbook]{standalone}
\input{plotdim.txt}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ 
    scale only axis, 
    width=\myplotwidth, 
    height=\myplotheight,
    xmin=0,xmax=12, 
    xlabel=fractions,
    ylabel=Small Axis,
 ]
\addplot[blue, mark=x] coordinates {(0,0)
    (1,2)(2,3)
    (3,4)(4,6)
    (5,11)(6,20)
    (7,15)(8,12)
    (9,8)(10,7)
    (11,3)(12,0)};
\end{axis}
\pgfresetboundingbox
\path
  ([xshift=-50pt]current axis.below south west)
  rectangle
  ([xshift=50pt]current axis.above north east)
;
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{standalone_plot_2.tex}
\documentclass[convert=false,class=scrbook]{standalone}
\input{plotdim.txt}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ 
    scale only axis,
    width=\myplotwidth, 
    height=\myplotheight,
    xmin=0,xmax=12, 
    xlabel=fractions,
    ylabel=Small Axis,
 ]
\addplot[blue, mark=x] coordinates {(0,0)
    (1,2)(2,3)
    (3,4)(4,6)
    (5,11)(6,200)
    (7,15)(8,12)
    (9,8)(10,7)
    (11,3)(12,0)};
\end{axis}
\pgfresetboundingbox
\path
  ([xshift=-50pt]current axis.below south west)
  rectangle
  ([xshift=50pt]current axis.above north east)
;
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{standalone_plot_3.tex}
\documentclass[convert=false,class=scrbook]{standalone}
\input{plotdim.txt}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ 
    scale only axis, 
    width=\myplotwidth, 
    height=\myplotheight,
    xmin=0,xmax=12, 
    xlabel=fractions,
    %ylabel=Small Axis,
 ]
\addplot[blue, mark=x] coordinates {(0,0)
    (1,2)(2,3)
    (3,4)(4,6)
    (5,11)(6,200)
    (7,15)(8,12)
    (9,8)(10,7)
    (11,3)(12,0)};
\end{axis}
\pgfresetboundingbox
\path
  ([xshift=-50pt]current axis.below south west)
  rectangle
  ([xshift=50pt]current axis.above north east)
;
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[]{scrbook}
\usepackage{showframe}% to show the page layout
\usepackage[textwidth=455.24945pt]{geometry}
\newlength\myplotwidth
\newlength\myplotheight
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \setlength\myplotwidth{\dimexpr\textwidth*3/4\relax}
  \setlength\myplotheight{\dimexpr\textheight/10\relax}
  \newwrite\textdim
  \immediate\openout\textdim=plotdim.txt
  \immediate\write\textdim{\string\newcommand\string\myplotwidth\string{\the\myplotwidth\string}}%
  \immediate\write\textdim{\string\newcommand\string\myplotheight\string{\the\myplotheight\string}}%
  \immediate\closeout\textdim
}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, positioning, calc, matrix}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\usepackage{standalone}
\standaloneconfig{mode=build}
% tex = use sourcefile, default
% image = use existing image file produced by the source file
% build = build image from source, then use it
% buildmissing= only build image if it does not exist
% buildnew = only build image if source file is newer 
 \begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!ht]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left,trim axis right]
    \begin{axis}[
    scale only axis,
    width=\myplotwidth, 
    height=\myplotheight,
    xlabel={Some Data},
    ylabel={Some Value},
    ]
    \addplot[very thick, red, mark=x] coordinates {(0,0)
        (1,2)(2,3)
        (3,4)(4,6)
        (5,11)(6,20)
        (7,15)(8,12)
        (9,8)(10,7)
        (11,3)(12,0)};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{A plot in the Document} 
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
    \centering
    \includestandalone{standalone_plot_1}
    \caption{Almost same plot but as Standalone}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[!ht]
    \centering
    \includestandalone{standalone_plot_2}
    \caption{Y-Values are getting bigger}
\end{figure}        
\begin{figure}[!ht]
    \centering
    \includestandalone{standalone_plot_3}
    \caption{Bigger Y-values and no Y Label}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

---

**Original answer** (works only for `mode=tex`)

`trim axis left` and `trim axis right` must be provided as option of the `tikzpicture` environment and not the `axis` environment.

To ensure that the tick and axis labels are not clipped away I would use `\makebox`.

[image]

```
\begin{filecontents*}{standalone_plot.tex}
\documentclass[ class=scrbook, 
                convert=false,
                margin=0pt
                ]{standalone}
\usepackage[textwidth=455.24945pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}    
\makebox[\dimexpr.75\textwidth+100pt\relax]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left,trim axis right]
    \begin{axis}[ 
        scale only axis, 
        width=0.75\textwidth, 
        height=0.1\textheight,
        xmin=0,xmax=12, 
        xlabel=fractions,
        ylabel=Small Axis,
     ]
    \addplot[blue, mark=x] coordinates {(0,0)
        (1,2)(2,3)
        (3,4)(4,6)
        (5,11)(6,20)
        (7,15)(8,12)
        (9,8)(10,7)
        (11,3)(12,0)};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{standalone_plot_2.tex}
\documentclass[ class=scrbook, 
                convert=false,
                margin=0pt
                ]{standalone}
\usepackage[textwidth=455.24945pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}    
\makebox[\dimexpr.75\textwidth+100pt\relax]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left,trim axis right]
    \begin{axis}[ 
        scale only axis,
        width=0.75\textwidth, 
        height=0.1\textheight,
        xmin=0,xmax=12, 
        xlabel=fractions,
        ylabel=Small Axis,
     ]
    \addplot[blue, mark=x] coordinates {(0,0)
        (1,2)(2,3)
        (3,4)(4,6)
        (5,11)(6,200)
        (7,15)(8,12)
        (9,8)(10,7)
        (11,3)(12,0)};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{standalone_plot_3.tex}
\documentclass[ class=scrbook, 
                convert=false,
                margin=0pt
                ]{standalone}
\usepackage[textwidth=455.24945pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}    
\makebox[\dimexpr.75\textwidth+100pt\relax]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left,trim axis right]
    \begin{axis}[ 
        scale only axis, 
        width=0.75\textwidth, 
        height=0.1\textheight,
        xmin=0,xmax=12, 
        xlabel=fractions,
        %ylabel=Small Axis,
     ]
    \addplot[blue, mark=x] coordinates {(0,0)
        (1,2)(2,3)
        (3,4)(4,6)
        (5,11)(6,200)
        (7,15)(8,12)
        (9,8)(10,7)
        (11,3)(12,0)};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[]{scrbook}
 \usepackage{showframe}% to show the page layout
 \usepackage[textwidth=455.24945pt]{geometry}
 \usepackage{pgfplots}
 \usetikzlibrary{arrows, positioning, calc, matrix}
 \pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

 \usepackage{standalone}
 \standaloneconfig{mode=tex}
 % tex = use sourcefile, default
 % image = use existing image file produced by the source file
 % build = build image from source, then use it
 % buildmissing= only build image if it does not exist
 % buildnew = only build image if source file is newer 
 \begin{document}

    \begin{figure}[!ht]
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left,trim axis right]
        \begin{axis}[
        scale only axis,
        width=0.75\textwidth, 
        height=0.1\textheight,
        xlabel={Some Data},
        ylabel={Some Value},
        ]
        \addplot[very thick, red, mark=x] coordinates {(0,0)
            (1,2)(2,3)
            (3,4)(4,6)
            (5,11)(6,20)
            (7,15)(8,12)
            (9,8)(10,7)
            (11,3)(12,0)};
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{A plot in the Document} 
    \end{figure}

    \begin{figure}[!ht]
        \centering
        \includestandalone{standalone_plot}
        \caption{Almost same plot but as Standalone}
    \end{figure}
    \begin{figure}[!ht]
        \centering
        \includestandalone{standalone_plot_2}
        \caption{Y-Values are getting bigger}
    \end{figure}        
    \begin{figure}[!ht]
        \centering
        \includestandalone{standalone_plot_3}
        \caption{Bigger Y-values and no Y Label}
    \end{figure}

 \end{document}
```

Note that `pgfplots` loads `tikz` which loads `xcolor` and `graphicx`.

Comment: Very nice. Works well used with `\standaloneconfig{mode=tex}` changing that to `buildnew` , to use to real function of Standalone separating the plots in different pdfs and reduce compile time, gives a bad result. The x-Axis values are missing. The seperated pdf plots have a big white space at the right side which than results in a left shift of the plots to the in text plot. Maybe you know why.

Comment: See my updated answer. The problem seems to be the `geometry` package in the standalone files. Its usage in a standalone file does not make sense (as @JohnKormylo has already said).

Comment: Thanks a lot, i reduced the standalone template to the neccessary. Now set the textwidth manually, use a box to avoid cropping problems.  See my next Answer. There are now to things remaining which i will post as new questions. 1. Setting Tex or Build still results in different layout, the y-labels are nearer or farer. 2. cropping let a big whitspace after the x-label, which than results in to big whitspace from x-label to caption.

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't it be easier just to find a good size for your plots (possibly using `\rule`) in terms of absolute coordinates, or use `\the\textwidth` to record the width in points, than try to combine standalone and geometry in any sort of meaningful way?

Anyway, a simple solution to your alignment problem is to place a standard box around each pgfplot inside the tikzpicture.  The origin is located at the lower left corner of the axis box.  Use `\draw` to verify the fit and `\path` to reserve the space.

For example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots} 

\begin{document}    

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ 
    scale only axis, % the width specifies the width of the axis only not the labels etc.
    width=8cm, 
    height=2cm,
    xmin=0,xmax=12, 
    xlabel=fractions,
    ylabel=Small Axis,
 ]
\addplot[blue, mark=x] coordinates {(0,0)
    (1,2)(2,3)
    (3,4)(4,6)
    (5,11)(6,20)
    (7,15)(8,12)
    (9,8)(10,7)
    (11,3)(12,0)};
\end{axis}
\path (-1.5,-1) rectangle (8.5,2.5);% standard box
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I removed all uneccessary things as you mentioned, added the with as fixed with and did some other little changes, that seemed to help. Here is my solution now. See the comment above that refers to the remaining Problems.

```
\documentclass[ class=scrbook, 
                convert=false,
                border=0pt,% no borders
                ]{standalone}
% if axis option " only scale axis" is used border has to be set manually to avoid cropping of the Y-Axis Label. Including the standalone then has to be set to \standaloneconfig{mode=tex}
% Using border={0pt 0pt 0pt 0pt} seems not to work with scrbook

% set KOMA options
\KOMAoptions{fontsize=12pt} % Fontsize

% the textwidth of the main docement is 16cm=455.24945pt
\newcommand{\originalTextWidth}{455.24945pt}
\newcommand{\originalTextHeight}{591.53027pt}

\usepackage{pgfplots} 

% Option that should not be change by the user, this are set here so it is obvious and makes the code more readable
\pgfplotsset{
    every axis/.append style={
        width=0.75*\originalTextWidth, 
        height=0.1*\originalTextHeight,
        scale only axis, % the width and height specifies only axis not the labels etc. to avoid missplacing of the different plots when Labels are used or not.
    },
}
\tikzset{every picture/.style={trim axis left, trim axis right}}% used to avoid missplacing of different plots when the numbers on the x-axis stands out left or right.

\begin{document}%   
\makebox[\dimexpr\originalTextWidth\relax]{% Box to avoid problem of standalone cropping too much of the plot.  
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xmin=0,xmax=12,%
        xlabel= \fbox{fractions q y Pp f g},
    %ylabel=Small Axis,
 ]%
\addplot[blue, mark=x] coordinates {(0,0)
    (1,2)(2,3)
    (3,4)(4,6)
    (5,11)(6,200)
    (7,15)(8,12)
    (9,8)(10,7)
    (11,3)(12,0)};
\end{axis}
\draw [brown] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);%
\end{tikzpicture}% Never Remove this comment to avoid missplacing plot shifts to left side a little bit
}%End \makebox
\end{document}
```